# setting up single sign on with django-mama-cas

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, cas

I am using django-mama-cas for sso but it is not working.

In local, I can login using 
 after run

```
http://app1.com:8000/login/
```

i got message 'you are logged in', 
but when i call to login using

```
http://app2.com:8000/login/
```

It redirect me to login page as an anonymous user

for mama-cas i follow

```
    $ pip install django-mama-cas
    Add to INSTALLED_APPS and run migrate:

    INSTALLED_APPS += ('mama_cas',)
    Include the URLs:

    urlpatterns += [url(r'', include('mama_cas.urls'))]
    See the full installation instructions for details.

    Upgrade

    Upgrade with pip:

    $ pip install --upgrade django-mama-cas
```

How can i fix this issue